# How to retrieve key value pairs from URL using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, url

I am working on a python 2.7 script such that given an URL with certain number of key-value pairs (not fixed numer of them), retrieves this values on a json structure.

This is what I have done so far:

```
from furl import furl

url = "https://search/address?size=10&city=Madrid&offer_type=1&query=Gran%20v"

f = furl(url) 
fields = ['size', 'city', 'offer_type', 'query']

l = []
l.append(f.args['size'])
l.append(f.args['city'])
l.append(f.args['offer_type'])
l.append(f.args['query'])

body = {
        fields[0]: f.args[fields[0]],
        fields[1]: f.args[fields[1]],
        fields[2]: f.args[fields[2]],
        fields[3]: f.args[fields[3]]
    }
```

This code works, but just for the case in which I know that there will be 4 key-value pairs, and the names of those pairs. I do not know how to face the problem if, for example, my url is shorter or larger.

Using this command `length = len(f.args)` I can obtain the number of pairs, but no idea of how to extract the key names from the `f.args` object

Thank you very much,
Álvaro

Comment: `list(f.args)` or `f.args.keys()`? Usually a dict-like object returns its keys when you call `list()` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

```
from furl import furl

url = "https://search/address?size=10&city=Madrid&offer_type=1&query=Gran%20v"

f = furl(url) 

print zip(f.args.keys(),f.args.values())
```

Output:

`[('size', '10'), ('city', 'Madrid'), ('offer_type', '1'), ('query', 'Gran v')]`

Comment: OP specifically wants a dict.

Comment: Welp, I guess not, have a +1

Answer (score 4):

I'm slightly confused... `f.args` is already a dictionary-like object of the type you want. If you want to explicitly convert it to a dictionary, you can use:

```
body = dict(f.args)
```

But even this seems unnecessary. If you want a new copy of the object so that you can change it without affecting the original instance, you can call the `.copy()` method.

Comment: Most you'd need is `f.args.copy()`. Well seen.

Answer (score 1):

The [`furl`](https://github.com/gruns/furl) library is not especially well documented, but digging through the source code shows that `f.args` is a property that redirects eventually to an [`orderedmultidict.omdict`](https://github.com/gruns/orderedmultidict) object. This supports all the standard dictionary methods, in addition to lots more interesting stuff (also not well documented).

You can therefore just use `f.args` wherever you need `body`. If you need a copy for some reason, do `f.args.copy()`, or possibly `dict(f.args)`.